# Grid row misalignment in gridview after selectindexchanged in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview

One gridview row is misalignmening after clicking Gridview row. It is moving towards to next cell.

This is happening only IE, Not in Chrome or Firefox. What could me the problem?

[image]